# Are there other ember.js source hosting URLs?

Tags: ember.js

Does anyone know alternatives to:

```
http://emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/getting-started/ember.js
```

because that url has stalled on multiple occasions now.  (Last hang: July 1st, 2013 9:05ish PM Pacific Time for at least 5 minutes.)

Sure I can keep a local version, but I'm wondering if there are any online versions.

Small side question: Does anyone know why it hangs or when it will hang?

---

Update: Thanks Mike!

- [Ember Latest Stable](http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-latest-stable.js)
- [Ember Data Latest](http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-data-latest.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find builds of emberjs and ember-data at http://builds.emberjs.com - for example:

- [ember-latest-stable.js](http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-latest-stable.js)
- [ember-latest](http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-latest.js)

Also check out https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md which includes links to preconfigured [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/) and [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/239/edit)

```
// http://builds.emberjs.com
```

Also you can find tagged releases of ember and many other js libraries at [CDNJS](http://cdnjs.com). For example:

[1.0.0-rc.6](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.0.0-rc.6/ember.js)
.

Comment: Is the ember-latest-stable the preferred version?

Comment: Hard to say what is "preferred" - depends on what you're doing.